# In my rate calculator, my AJAX operation causes a white screen

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

In my distance/rate calculator (for distance I am using Google Maps) I implemented AJAX and I am getting error white screen.

```
<?
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once("patch/require.php");
function curl_request($sURL,$sQueryString=null)
{
    $cURL=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_URL,$sURL.'?'.$sQueryString);
    curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $cResponse=trim(curl_exec($cURL));
    curl_close($cURL);
    return $cResponse;
}
if(isset($_POST))
{
$dest= str_replace(',','',str_replace(' ','+',trim($_POST['to'])));
$origin =str_replace(',','',str_replace(' ','+',trim($_POST['from']))); 
$sResponse=curl_request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json','origins='.$origin.'&destinations='.$dest.'&mode=driving&units=metric&sensor=false');
$oJSON=json_decode($sResponse);
if ($oJSON->status=='OK')
    $fDistanceInKM=(float)preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/','',$oJSON->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text);
else
    $fDistanceInKM=0;
      $oJSON->destination_addresses[0];
      $oJSON->origin_addresses[0];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['getTravel']))
    {
        $_SESSION['getTravel']=time();
    }
    $session_id=$_SESSION['getTravel'];
    $origin=mysql_real_escape_string($oJSON->origin_addresses[0]);
    $destination=mysql_real_escape_string($oJSON->destination_addresses[0]);
    $distance=mysql_real_escape_string($fDistanceInKM.PHP_EOL);
    $increase=(int)$_POST['inc'];
    $checkQ=mysql_query("select * from temp_travel where `session_id`='$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
    $cms_distance_lower=number_format(Functions::getConf(3113),2);
    $cms_distance_upper=number_format(Functions::getConf(3116),2);
    $cms_lower_price=number_format(Functions::getConf(3111),2);
    $cms_between_price=number_format(Functions::getConf(3112),2);
    $cms_upper_price=number_format(Functions::getConf(3117),2);
    $cms_bag_price=number_format(Functions::getConf(3114),2);
    $cms_handcarry_price=number_format(Functions::getConf(3115),2);
    $distance=(int)$distance;
    if($distance<=$cms_distance_lower)
    {
        $pr=$cms_lower_price;
    }
    else if($distance>$cms_distance_lower && $distance<=$cms_distance_upper)
    {
        $pr=$cms_between_price;
    }
    else
    {
        $pr=$distance*$cms_upper_price;
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkQ)>0)
    {
        $check=mysql_fetch_array($checkQ);
        $check_id=(int)$check['Id'];
        $passenger=$check['passenger'];
        if($passenger<4)
    {
        $hd=3;
        $bg=3;
    }
    else 
    {
        $pr+=($passenger-3)*8;
        if($passenger<6 )
        {
            $hd=3;
        }
        else
        {
            $hd=$passenger-2;
        }
        $bg=$passenger;
    }
        $handcarry=$check['handcarry'];
        $baggage=$check['baggage'];
        $price=number_format($pr+($cms_handcarry_price*($handcarry))+($cms_bag_price*($baggage))+$check['increase'],2);
        mysql_query("update temp_travel set `origin`='$origin',`destination`='$destination',`distance`='$distance',`increase`='$increase',`price`='$price' where `Id`='$check_id'")or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $price=number_format(($pr+$increase),2);
        mysql_query("insert into temp_travel (`session_id`,`origin`,`destination`,`distance`,`increase`,`price`,`handcarry`,`baggage`) values ('$session_id','$origin','$destination','$distance','$increase','$price','','')")or die(mysql_error());
    }

}           
        include('infotable.php');
?>
```

I am saving response from this page in getValue of ajax call but getting error which is in question. When I submit request a blank white page comes and it didn't do anything;
don't know the reason:

> Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Goto this link http://www.airporttaxibooking.ca/ and check the RateCalculator.

Here is my .js file from which I'm sending request:

```
$('#ptext').focus(function () { $('input:text[name=pearson-code]').val('');  });
$('#ptext').blur(function () {      
if($('input:text[name=pearson-code]').val()!='')
        {
        $('input:text[name=tpearson-code]').val('');
        $('.ptext').attr('disabled','true');
            var from= $('input:text[name=pearson-code]').val();
            var inc=$('input:radio[name=pdestination]:checked').val();  
            var to ="Mississauga, ON L4W 1S9, Canada";
            var data='from='+from+'&inc='+inc+'&to='+to;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "distance.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(getValue) {
            $('#cbox-2').html(getValue);
        }
        });
    $('.ptext').removeAttr('disabled','true');      
        }
    return false;
});
```

And here is infotable.php file:

```
<?
include("patch/require.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['getTravel']))
{
    $session_id=$_SESSION['getTravel'];
    $travel_infoQ=mysql_query("select * from temp_travel where `session_id`='$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($travel_infoQ)>0)
    {
        $travel_info=mysql_fetch_array($travel_infoQ);
        $destination=stripslashes($travel_info['destination']);
        $origin=stripslashes($travel_info['origin']);
        $distance=stripslashes($travel_info['distance']);
        $passenger=stripslashes($travel_info['passenger']);
        $handcarry=stripslashes($travel_info['handcarry']);
        $baggage=stripslashes($travel_info['baggage']);
        $increase=stripslashes($travel_info['increase']);
        $cms_distance_lower=Functions::getConf(3113);
        $cms_distance_upper=Functions::getConf(3116);
        $cms_lower_price=Functions::getConf(3111);
        $cms_between_price=Functions::getConf(3112);
        $cms_upper_price=Functions::getConf(3117);
        $cms_bag_price=Functions::getConf(3114);
        $cms_handcarry_price=Functions::getConf(3115);
        $distance=(int)$distance;
        if($distance<=$cms_distance_lower)
        {
            $pr=$cms_lower_price;
        }
        else if($distance>$cms_distance_lower && $distance<=$cms_distance_upper)
        {
            $pr=$cms_between_price;
        }
        else
        {
            $pr=$distance*$cms_upper_price;
        }


        if($passenger<4)
        {
            $hd=3;
            $bg=3;
        }
        else 
        {
            $pr+=($passenger-3)*8;
            if($passenger<6 )
            {
                $hd=3;
            }
            else
            {
                $hd=$passenger-2;
            }
            $bg=$passenger;
        }   
        $price=$pr+$cms_handcarry_price*($handcarry)+$cms_bag_price*($baggage)+$increase;
        mysql_query("update temp_travel set `price`='$price' where `session_id`='$session_id'");
    }
}
?>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"   cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="td" valign="top" width="35%" ><strong>From :</strong></td>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><? echo $destination; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><strong>To :</strong> </td>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><? echo $origin; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><strong>Passengers :</strong> </td>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><div id="passenger"><? echo $passenger; ?></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td" colspan="2" style="text-align:center; background:#ffffff;" valign="top"><strong>Number of Baggages</strong> </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><strong>Large Baggages :</strong> </td>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><? if(!empty($baggage)){ echo '<div id="luggage2">'.$bg.'</div> <div id="baggage"> + '. $baggage.'</div>'; }else { echo $bg; } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><strong>Hand Carries :</strong> </td>
        <td class="td" valign="top"><? if(!empty($handcarry)){ echo '<div id="luggage1">'.$hd.'</div> + <div id="baggage">'. $handcarry.'</div>';}else { echo $hd; } ?></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:center" colspan="2"><strong >Price : $<div id="price"><? echo $price ?></div></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;" align="center"><button id="button" onclick="document.location='<?=_WEB_URL?>bookingform.php'">Book Now</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got several problems. Your immediate bug is that when you type in a postal code of "123" and click 'Refresh', the AJAX operation starts but you've not prevented the event from bubbling through to the default action - which is to submit the form to another page. Thus, the AJAX operation often (but not always) terminates because its parent page is being reloaded - it depends which loads first. (This might also happen if you have JavaScript errors in your event handler).

There are also JS errors associated with clicking on the radio buttons. Are you using a developer toolbar? Safari and Chrome have one natively, and Firefox has the excellent Firebug plugin. This is an *essential* part of your AJAX debugging toolkit, and should be on-screen for all stuff like this.

I notice your AJAX urls ([this GET](http://www.airporttaxibooking.ca/passenger.php?score=3) and [this POST](http://www.airporttaxibooking.ca/distance.php)) render the whole page if viewed outside of an AJAX request. This makes it harder to test separately - you should be able to load those in a separate browser window and get a JSON answer. Finally unless the POST op changes something on your server, that should be a GET operation too.

Comment: I have done some edits in questions .....You can see im my console i logged result of reponse and that is not comming from infotable.php as it should be from that file

Comment: Ha ha, you'll kick yourself for this one! I should have spotted this before. It's not that clicks are bubbling through to the default submit action; in fact, your button has this attribute: `onclick=" document.location='http://www.airporttaxibooking.ca/?hamilton';"`. Remove that, and just attach a click-handler in jQuery instead: `$('button').click(function() { ... });`. You certainly don't want to redirect - I am guessing you should be kicking off an AJAX op at this point (though of course only you know what it is meant to do).

Comment: Right I got that but The problem is when i write something in to Postal code then after when onBlur function is fired the data which is returned is not coming from infotable....at that point i did'nt fired click onclick=" document.location='http://www.airporttaxibooking.ca/?hamilton';" event

Comment: and is this error causing any problem to my code ( Could not send response: Cannot send a response more than once per chrome.extension.onRequest listener per document (message was sent by extension gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom).  Thanks for your reponse so far

Comment: If I type '123' in the postal field and then tab out, it kicks off an AJAX op to 'test.php' and then then does another immediate redirect again. I would fix that first, as well as the incorrect `onclick` I mentioned (you don't need inline JS events _at all_ with jQuery - remove all of them!).